# Can't login to Samba share with any user other than my own user

Tags: server, permissions, login, password, samba

I've followed the usual steps for adding a new user to Samba:

- create new Linux user with `useradd [user]`
- set its password with `passwd [user]`
- set its Samba password with `smbpasswd -a [user]`

But when I try to connect to my server with this user, I always get some form of "authentication failed" on the clients, and `NT_STATUS_WRONG_PASSWORD` in the server logs. (The password is correct, and is the same password between both the Linux and Samba users.) The same problem happens on every subsequent Linux/Samba user I try creating, and persists after several reboots.
The weird part is, I can still log in to the share using my own linux user without any issues; just not with the new user(s). I've tried pretty much everything, including disabling every single security measure e.g. NTLMv1 (although i was still able to log in with NTLMv2 using my own linux user) and setting all shares to public. Could anyone help me figure this out? I can provide logs if requested.

(I'm on Xubuntu 22.04 with Samba version `4.15.5-Ubuntu`)

Output of `testparm -s`:

```
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
Loaded services file OK.
Weak crypto is allowed

Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE

# Global parameters
[global]
    allow insecure wide links = Yes
    dns proxy = No
    log file = /usr/local/samba/var/log.%m
    max log size = 50
    server role = standalone server
    server string = Samba Server
    workgroup = MYGROUP
    idmap config * : backend = tdb


[printers]
    browseable = No
    comment = All Printers
    path = /usr/spool/samba
    printable = Yes


[depo]
    comment = depo
    path = /pub/
    read only = No
    wide links = Yes
```

Comment: Please edit your post and add the output of the following command: `testparm -s`

Comment: @Morbius1 I've now edited the post with its output.

Comment: What are the clients ? what OS and version ?

Comment: @RowlandPenny I've tried several: standard File Explorer on Windows 10 and Windows 7, and X-plore + Samsung File Manager on Android 11. All of these clients have no problem when connecting to my own Linux user; but they fail when connecting to the new users.

Comment: Windows 10 should have worked because it, like your version of Samba, uses SMBv2 or 3 by default. Windows 7 (unless you have modified it) uses SMBv1 by default, I presume your android client is the same (have you tried a different android client that states it uses SMBv2/3 ). It shouldn't matter which user connects, if one Samba user connects, then all users should be able to, unless the underlying OS permissions deny access.

Comment: @RowlandPenny I know.. yet I can't understand why the other users don't work - I can connect to them locally through `//localhost/` on `smbclient` just fine; but i can't get any client to connect to them externally.

Comment: Did you add the new user to the `smbusers` file?

Comment: @OrganicMarble My installation did not have an `/etc/samba/smbusers` file but I created one and added the user as a line; it still didn't work after a `smbd` restart.

Comment: Did you use the syntax `username = "username"` in the smbusers file? Permissions are `-rw-r-----`

Comment: @OrganicMarble I've edited the file to match the syntax and permissions you mentioned; result is still the same - every client (except smbclient on localhost) throws auth errors.

Comment: Weird, except for that, everything you did is what I did.

Comment: I do have lines in my `smb.conf` under the share heading like `valid users = username` but I doubt the lack of that would cause it to fail authentication.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I've tried adding the new users under `valid users =` but all it did was prevent my main account from connecting (with `NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED` on smbclient) but all added users still kept throwing auth errors when I tried connecting to them outside of localhost. I honestly don't know what the culprit is..

Comment: If you can connect to localhost, but not externally, could it be something like a firewall stopping connection ?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out @Za-? I'm having the exact same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing worked for me either. I tried creating a linux user and kept trying to access samba share but it'd never work. I also tried SSH-ing in once as that new user but that didn't work either.

After I added a samba user manually, and set it's password, it worked:
`sudo smbpasswd -a {user}`

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. In my case, I was not able to login with the new user because my newly created user did not have access to the directories that I was sharing through Samba.

Note that, not only Samba needs to share the directories for the user, the user first needs to have linux level access to those directories. In my case, I had to add the user to the group which the directory belonged to. This fixed the issue.